# How to separate training set and validation set using 80/20 rule?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, computer-vision

I have two folders: One folder contains images of non-dogs, and the second folder contains images of dogs. I am to divide these folders into a "training set" and a "validation set" with the 80/20 rule.

For the training set, I added 80% of the images from the dog folder and 80% of the images from non-dog folder.

For the validation set, I added 20% of the images from the dog folder and 20% of the images from the non-dog folder.

This is how I interpreted and done the split, is this correct?

Comment: Did you choose which files examples to move at random?

Comment: Single split-sample validation requires an enormous sample size before "the luck of the split" is not a danger.  If you sample size is non-huge you would be better off using resampling validation (e.g., optimism bootstrap or 100 repeats of 10-fold cross validation) repeating all supervised learning steps afresh at each sample.

Comment: Make sure you did not include any samples in both splits!